# What is the abbreviation standard that the U.S. Customs and Border Protection's travel history is following for the locations?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, history

What is the abbreviation standard that  the U.S. Customs and Border Protection's [travel history](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/history-search) is following for the locations?

E.g. I see BOS = Boston; HOU = Houston; LOS = Los Angeles; SEA = Seattle; SFR = San Francisco.

[image]

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are we supposed to fill out that form to see these abbreviations?

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim anyway, those of us who are US citizens can't get anything out of that form.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim yes, unless they're listed somewhere else, which don't know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is CBP's own system.  I couldn't find a list on the CBP site, but they provide the list to the State Department, which includes it in the Foreign Affairs Manual at [9 FAM 102.5-3](https://fam.state.gov/fam/09FAM/09FAM010205.html#M102_5_3).

Comment: Haha, found Rome (the "real" Rome) as a port of entry

Comment: @Crazydre https://www.dhs.gov/news/2016/11/04/dhs-announces-11-new-airports-selected-possible-preclearance-expansion-following.